# 3-way dimmer switch schematic

Tags: mains, dimmer

I am building an AC dimmer circuit to control from an Arduino using this schematic:

[image: Schematic]

I need to make this dimmer so that it can be used as a three way switch as well.  How would I modify this circuit to work in place of a three way switch?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to control three light bulbs independently?

Comment: Or, do you want three separate switches controlling one lamp?

Comment: No, I want to have two switches control the same circuit.  I.e top and bottom of staircase

Answer (score 2):

I would have both switches connected to the Arduino, with the Arduino firmware allowing both switches to control the same dimmer.

For this to work, you would have "bright" and "dim" switches at both control points, rather than having a pot somewhere to control the dimmer. (For bonus points, you could have rotary encoders at both locations, rather than switches.  :-)  )

Answer (score 0):

Here's what a three way switch circuit looks like: -

[image]

If you only need two locations then omit the more complicated DPDT in the centre: -

[image]

Should it be that you want the switches going to the MCU then please note that they enact the logical ex-or function.

Comment: ok, but how would I integrate the dimmer circuit in so that the other switch works if turned off from the dimmer?

Comment: Put the dimmer anywhere in series with the load OR put two dimmers in the two common lines between the switches; one controlled at one end and one controlled at the other. If you want either end to be able to dim the lamp then you need to wire pots to your MCU so that the correct pot is chosen as "master".